# Best Practices for Product Release Tagging

Tags: svn, version-control, repository, release-management

We have a (historically grown) repository structure (in our case using Subversion) like this:

```
trunk/
  Product1/
  Product2/
  Product3/
  Product4/
  CommonDependencyOfProduct1and2/
  SomeStructuringFolder/
    CommonDependencyOfProduct1and3/
    CommonDependencyOfProduct2and3/
  ...
```

When tagging releases for products without shared dependencies (Product4), everything seems pretty straight forward, we just create a tag from trunk/Product4 and be done with it.

However, when we release one of the other products, we also have to tag the shared dependencies. I see the following options:

1. **Create a tag of the entire repository**

   - PRO: Easy to automate, and tag follows trunk structure
   - CON: Will include (not necessarily obviously) unrelated products, making it unclear what actually belongs to the release and what doesn't (ugly for QA documentation).
2. **Create a tag of the entire repository, and then remove all unrelated folders**

   - PRO: No unrelated code included, and tag still follows trunk structure
   - CON: Afaik, modifying tags is still considered really bad practice. Also, it is hard to automate (list of to-be-kept or to-be-removed products needs to be maintained).
3. **Create a new, empty release top-level folder beforehand in the tags/ section and then create tags of the released project and all its dependencies as sub-folders**

   - PRO: No unrelated code included, still relatively easy to automate
   - CON: Tag no longer reflects trunk structure. Also, copying the different parts to the new folder may still count as modification of a tag.

A fourth option would be moving each component to a separate repository, but would be quite disruptive to our infrastructure, so I'd like to weigh up alternatives first.

The same problem somewhat applies to the creation of work branches. Only there, we don't usually care about modifications or the inclusion of unrelated code so much, so that options 1 or 2 are usually acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

1. Create product specific branches, say /branches/product1,
   /branches/product2 etc
2. Do the development on these branches. Whenever the release of a
   particular product is ready, create a tag of the product release
   from branch and then merge that branch to /trunk. This way your trunk will
   always have release-ready code and no unwanted code. Also
   product-release specific tag will come handy in future.
3. Post merge, create a release-specific tag of entire /trunk.

Is this feasible? Though it will add overhead of frequent merging between branches.
Also as you already mentioned, its always better to have different repos for products having different releases. It will be easy to scale and automate.

Comment: I agree that development is often performed on branches, especially when the deadline is approaching. Can you elaborate how you would create those "product specific branches", i.e. using method 1, 2 or 3 from my original post? And how you would manage the development on a shared dependency on two different product branches repository-wise?

Comment: I will suggest to use branches for 2 purposes. One type for product-specific and other type for common/shared dependencies.
Create all branches (branch/product1, branch/commonProduct1and3 etc)from trunk and remove unwanted content from branches (2nd approach from original post).

This will be easy in terms of scaling, but you will have lots of tags and frequent merging will be required.
So whenever you need to tag/merge product-specific branch, you'll need to do the same with common/shared dependency branch.